# x-editable : turn off inline editing for non admin users

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, x-editable

I am using X-Editable plugin for inline editing with angular.js
In-line editing is working perfect. But, I want to disable this feature for non-admin users.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="OnaftersaveCtrl">
   <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onaftersave="updateUser()">
   {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
   </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);
app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
});

app.controller('OnaftersaveCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.user = {
  id: 1,
  name: '<?=$test?>'
};

$scope.updateUser = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/test',
        data: $scope.user,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      }).
      success(function(response) {
          alert(response);
      }).
      error(function(response) {
          alert("not ok");
      });
      return false;
    };
```

});

I tried to putting html code in the id.

```
$('#myselector').editable('option', 'disabled', true);
```

But, It's not rendering the initial value. (here it's test variable which is coming from php).

Answer (score 0):

I need to have the same functionality, I found a few issues on https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/pull/206, but non of them wore fixed. I had to finish fast my task so I choose to replace the element with anotherone that dosent have the editable atributs.

```html
<i>
<span ng-if="accounts.editOptions.isEditable" editable-text="account.clientCompanyXMLEntity.industry" ng-bind="account.clientCompanyXMLEntity.industry || 'add industry'"></span> 
<span ng-if="!accounts.editOptions.isEditable" ng-bind="account.clientCompanyXMLEntity.industry || 'add industry'"></span>
</i>
```

And in my controller I have:

```js
$scope.accounts.editOptions.isEditable = false;
$scope.accounts.editOptions.toggleEditability = function() {
    $scope.accounts.editOptions.isEditable = !$scope.accounts.editOptions.isEditable;
};
```